# Application Size Increases When Setting Application Icon from Resources

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resources

I have an application whose size is 16kb.

After adding an icon resource through the Project Properties menu, the application, as expected, increased to a size of 299kb.

Now, under Properties/Application when I set the Icon File to "Resource\IconName.ico" the file size again increases to 581kb.

Is this normal behavior? I understand that it increases when I add the icon as a resource, but not when I set the icon from the resources to the Application Icon.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

EDIT:

Maybe a better question would be how can I set the Application Icon using an icon from the Properties/Resources section?

Comment: What's the size of the icon file? The reason for the double in size when changing it again was probably because it was embedded in the executable twice

Comment: The icon size is 281kb. I don't understand why it would embed it twice since I'm using the icon that I already placed in the resources.

Comment: Well there is where your size increase is from. If an app is just a few kilos it sounds like a utility. Utilities generally don't have icons

Comment: Just wondering why its 581kb. I expect it to only embed once and stay a size of 299kb.

Comment: Did you remove it from the Project Properties menu? Cuz as I said, it may be embedded twice.

Comment: Deleting it from Project Properties menu does bring the file size back down, but then its not part of the resource anymore (obviously).

I need it as a resource so that I can set it to form icons like so:
this.Icon = Properties.Resource.IconName

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behaviour. Your icon isn't being stored as a resource twice (as suggested in some comments), it's simply being linked into the exe during compilation while also being stored as a resource. Since the icon is public-facing (i.e. explorer.exe accesses it directly when rendering the icon), you essentially end up with 2 copies of the icon in different formats:

- One copy of the icon compiled directly into the exe in a Windows-standard format
- One copy as a .NET resource

If you really want to save this extra space, remove the embedded resource, change your application icon reference to point straight to the icon on disk, then, when you need a copy of the icon to assign to your forms, extract it directly from the assembly:

```
var executablePath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(executablePath);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for the explanation! I would up-vote but I need 15 rep.

Comment: That technically is twice. That's what I meant

Comment: Very true, @ColeJohnson. I read your answer as implying "embedded twice as a resource", but on re-read, I see that you didn't say it was the same mode of embedding.