# Embedding resources size

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application developed in C# that does some stuff. I decided to embed an `.msi` I want to be called during a process. The `executable` size is around 5MB, and the `.msi` size is around 150MB. But when the new executable with the embedded .msi is compiled, is now 400MB!!

Why is this? Does embedding resources increment the final `.exe` size?

Comment: There has to be more going on than just adding a 5MB .msi file for your output file to be more than double the size. are you sure nothing is happening to the msi you're embedding?

Comment: How is the .msi embedded in your project?

Comment: I added it as an existing resource and I changed the `Build  Action` to Embedded Resource. I'm gonna check the .msi...

Comment: Just tried to embed 42,120 KB .msi file into a 5 KB project as Embeddd Resource, and the resulting .exe is 42,126 KB.

Comment: If you remove the .msi from your project now, will the .exe go back to 5MB?

Comment: It does... Weird, isn't it?

Comment: What if you try another .msi file?

Comment: With a 40MB .msi it doubles size. The .exe is around 85MB.

Comment: I discovered that if I add it from the `Resources` tab in the properties section, then it will double size (one for the resource and one because of the item being embedded). If I only add the item as Add->Existing item and then change the property to `Embedded Resource`, the size it's working fine!

Comment: Very good. Congratulations!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with a conclusion due to what a user posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12031260/760893).

When I add my `.msi` as a resource, I have at the end two copies of the same file. That's why I double size of my final executable.

- One copy of my `.msi` because it's linked as a resource in my project
- The other copy is because the compilation of the project links another copy of it

So I did the following:

- Delete the `.msi` from `Resources`
- On the folder I wanted it to be, I added it by simply calling `Add->Existing Item`
- Then I changed the `Build action` of the `.msi` to `Embedded Resource` and it's embedded in my aplication, but it's not being called twice as it's not considered a `Resource`

More or less this is the answer.

Comment: Awesome! My executable was 9MB even I only embedding 4MB of resources. The very same thing was happening: It was duplicated on the assembly. Removed from the `Project -> Properties -> Resources`, but set the files inside the `Folder Resources` (on the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio) as Embedded Resource, and everything worked perfectly! My executable is now high half the previous size (and working!)